# Numbering for each line in a .txt file

Tags: python

i wanna print all line of a txt file but before each line [n] (number of line) to be placed.

my code:

```
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open("test.txt"))
work = open("test.txt", "r")
for i in range(1, num_lines):
    print("["+str(i)+"]",work.readline(i))
work.close()
```

but my output is:

```
[1] 

[2] li
[3] ne1
[4]
```

but what i want for output :

```
[1] line1
[2] line2
[3] line3
[4] line4
```

please give right code Thanks.

Comment: `work.readline(i)` is wrong, just use `work.readline()` to read a single line. Don't pass a size argument or you get the wrong behavior you describe.

Comment: Also, you can use f-strings for formatted output, so: `print(f'[{i}]', work.readline())`

Comment: I would also suggest looking at the [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function.

Comment: If you had looked at `help(work.readline)` you'd see *"readline(size=-1, /) method of _io.TextIOWrapper instance. Read until newline or EOF."* You don't want to pass a *size* argument.

Answer (score 0):

Given the txt file is:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

You can first grab the content of the file:

```
python
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()
```

and then separate each line in a list using the *split* command:

```
python
contentList = content.split("\n")
```

This will split the content of the file for each *\n*, which is a new line in Python

You can then print it this way:

```
python
count = 0
for content in contentList:
    count += 1
    print(f"[{count}]: {content}")
```

In order to print the count variable which increments for each new line, and then print the content of the line.

The full code is here:

```py
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()

contentList = content.split("\n")

count = 0
for content in contentList:
    count += 1
    print(f"{count}: {content}")
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Try readlines() method instead

```
work = open('test.txt', 'r')
Lines = work.readlines()

count = 0
for line in Lines:
    count += 1
    print("[{}] Line: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
work.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read all the lines in with `readlines` then use list comprehension with `enumerate` to print them out with a number preceding each line.

```py
with open('test.csv') as work:
  data = work.readlines()

[print(f'{[row]} {line.rstrip()}') for row, line in enumerate(data,1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
  n = 1
  for line in f:
    print(f'[{n}]', line, end='')
    n += 1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.